# What's time complexity of algorithm for finding all Unique Binary Search Trees?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o, binary-search-tree

> **Unique Binary Search Trees** 
>   Given n,  generate all structurally unique
>   BST's (binary search trees) that store values 1...n.
>
> **For example**, Given n = 3,  
>   your program should return all 5 unique
>   BST's shown below.
>
> ```
>     1         3         3         2         1 
>      \       /         /         / \         \ 
>       3     2         1         1   3         2 
>      /     /           \                       \ 
>     2     1             2                       3
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Personally I think**,
>  time complexity = O(n^n), n is the input. 
>   **But what's more tight time complexity?**
>
> ---
>
> **C++**

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<TreeNode *> generateTrees(int n) {
        vector<TreeNode *> list;

        // Input validation.
        if (n <= 0) {
            list.push_back(NULL);
            return list;
        }

        int left = 1;
        int right = n;
        generateTrees(left, right, list);

        return list;
    }

    void generateTrees(int left, int right, vector<TreeNode *> &list) {
        // Base case.
        if (left > right) {
            list.push_back(NULL);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = left; i <= right; i ++) {
            vector<TreeNode *> left_trees;
            generateTrees(left, i - 1, left_trees);

            vector<TreeNode *> right_trees;
            generateTrees(i + 1, right, right_trees);

            for (vector<TreeNode *>::iterator left_it = left_trees.begin();
                 left_it != left_trees.end(); left_it ++) {

                TreeNode *leftTree = *left_it;

                for (vector<TreeNode *>::iterator right_it = right_trees.begin();
                     right_it != right_trees.end(); right_it ++) {

                    TreeNode *rightTree = *right_it;

                    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(i);
                    root->left = leftTree;
                    root->right = rightTree;

                    list.push_back(root);
                }         
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given n nodes, the total number of the binary search trees is the Catalan Number, please refer to this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number. So, the time complexity is also O(Catalan(n)).

Comment: Thank you dguan, description on wikipedia is a little complicated, I need some time to think about it......

Comment: Actually, you could think the problem like this: suppose the number of BSTs for n nodes is C(n), because we are building a BST, for each root node, there could be (0 -- n-1) nodes in left child tree and (n-1 -- 0) nodes in the right, respectively. So the total number of the BSTs C(n) = sum(C(i)*C(n-1-i)), i=0 -- n-1, which is exactly the recursive formula of the Catalan number Catalan(n).

Comment: Catalan(n) = C(n) = sum(C(i)*C(n-1-i)), i=0 -- n-1, since the time complexity = O(C(n)), so the time complexity = O(Catalan(n)). So the next question is how to get Catalan(n), this is the real hard part. Thank you dguan.

Comment: you could get C(n) either by directly using the recursive formula, which is very inefficient; or by using dynamic programming, whose space complexity is O(n) and time complexity is O(n^2), this is much much more efficient.

Comment: Yes dguan, but I need print out all BSTs, so I think I have to use recursion. If I just need the number of Catalan, the DP is a really good choice.

Comment: You are right, recursion seems the only choice to print out all BSTs.